# Adjoint transformation-isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:E\to E^*$ be an isomorphism, dim(E)=$n$

What is the difference between defining this isomorphism by using a base and defining it using an internal product in E?

What disadvantages does one have before the other?

I don't find much difference, but I was thinking in which cases the definition with the internal product transforms a base into its dual base, that is:

If $V=\{v_1,v_2, ...;v_n\}$ is a base of $E$, and $V^*=\{v_1^*,v_2^*, ...;v_n^*\}$ the corresponding dual base, so:

If defined $A:E\to E^*$ how: $Av=v^*$ such that $v^*=<w,v>$.

So why $Av_i=v_i^*$ you must have to  $v_i^*(w)=<\beta_1v_1+\cdots+\beta_iv_i+\cdots+\beta_nv_n , v_i>=\beta_i$ and this happens when the base $V$ is orthonormal.

Does this make a difference? or always happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $v_i$ being an orthonormal basis with respect to the inner product is both sufficient and necessary:

As you wrote, if they are an ONB we calculate $$\langle \sum \limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i, v_j\rangle = \lambda_j = v_j^{*}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lambda_iv_i\right).$$ Conversely we find that if $\langle w,v_j \rangle = v_j^{*}(w)$ for all $w$ then in particular $$\langle v_i,v_j \rangle = v_j^{*}(v_i) = \left \{ \begin{array}{ll} 1 & i=j\\ 0& i \neq j\end{array}\right.$$